# Javascript Code security

Tags: javascript, cordova, security, parse-platform

I have created a web application from Cross platform application development using javascript sdk of parse.com. What should I do to secure my Code, as entire code, API keys, client keys  gets visible once I view the page source.

Comment: Optimize your javascript code which will create unreadable code.

Comment: Use this plugin: https://github.com/tkyaji/cordova-plugin-crypt-file

Comment: I'd sugest to read through Parse's blog on Parse Security and continue from there. 1st part is here: http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-i-are-you-the-key-master/

Comment: Laxmikant Dange- Can you please describe a way to optimize the javascript code, I mean any software or website, and also tell me, that even after optimizing the code whether my API Keys will remain hidden or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is where a back-end can come into play, you make AJAX requests to the backend that has the API/Client keys as the backend source code is not visible. As far as not revealing your source code, I would recommend a JavaScript minifier.

Comment: the minifier will provide what is known as "security by obscurity". this is the weakest form of security available. On the other hand: The JavaScript must be visible, otherwise the browser could not execute it. So: The JavaScript will be visible and cannot really be secured. I fully agree with your suggestion for API keys though.

Comment: Can you please give a small example, where I can use AJAX request to backend that has the API/Client key.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in mobile apps (packed), its not very straight forward to check the source. One need to decompile to see whats happening behind the scene.

You have not shared the mode of your web app, whether it would be a mobile app or a web application running on browser.

Please share more details to understand and answer it better.

Comment: It's a web application running on browser.